# How to improve time format of a WPF Countdown timer

Tags: c#, wpf, datetime, format

I have a countdown timer here,Is there anyways to improve it to make it look better for the time to display 01:09 instead of 1:9 in the display and 00:09 instead of 00:9 below is the code.I need some guidance on how to do it.

```
private int time = 120;
private System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer Timer;

public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    Timer = new System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer();
    Timer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1);
    Timer.Tick += Timer_tick;
    Timer.Start();

}


void Timer_tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (time > 0)
    {
    if (time <= 10)
    {
        if (time % 2 == 0)
        {
            tbTime.Foreground = Brushes.Red;
        }
        else
        {
            tbTime.Foreground = Brushes.White;
        }


        time--;

        tbTime.Text = string.Format("00:0{0}:0{1}", time / 60, time % 60);

    }

    else
    {
        time--;
        tbTime.Text = string.Format("00:0{0}:{1}", time / 60, time % 60);


    }

    }
    else
    {
    Timer.Stop();
    }
}
```

Comment: Take a look on `DateTime` and `ToString`, they will help you greatly

Answer (score 2):

If you use DateTime to represent the "time" you could easily display it like

```
time.ToString("hh:mm");
```

If you insist on using integer, you could use this instead:

```
string.Format("00:{0:00}:{1:00}", time / 60, time % 60);
```

or use "d2" as suggested by Ian in his answer

```
string.Format("00:{0:d2}:{1:d2}", time / 60, time % 60);
```

Comment: Thank you for the help,it was really useful

Answer (score 1):

You might want to handle the formatting purely on  xaml and use a timespan instead of datetime in your viewmodel, also binding the brush from the viewmodel might be good, unless you want to use a trigger with value converter to check if the TotalSeconds is even or odd.

```
<TextBlock Width="100" Height="24" ForeGround={Binding ForeBrush}>
    <TextBlock.Text>
        <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}{0:00}:{1:00;00}">
            <Binding Path="MyTimeSpan.Minutes"/>
            <Binding Path="MyTimeSpan.Seconds"/>
        </MultiBinding>
    </TextBlock.Text>
</TextBlock>
```